# Getting SSL error in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have created google app engine application. It works fine in my local system and also deployee successfully on server. but that url http://****.appspot.com/_ah/api/employeeendpoint/v1/employee/1 gives me below response.

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"sslRequired","message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}],"code":403,"message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}}
```

I have also try with https://****.appspot.com/_ah/api/employeeendpoint/v1/employee/1 but still not working.

Comment: use https instead of http?

Comment: @rene It's also give same response to me, I have already try it.

Comment: Don't you think that you should have included that info **IN** your question? You know how to use the [edit] link I assume?

Comment: Which APIs are you using in your application?
some APIs as Cloud Endpoints require SSL.

Comment: From the error it looks like the client doesn't support SSL, while Endpoints do require it. Can you curl -I -tlsv1 https://****.appspot.com/_ah/api/employeeendpoint/v1/employee/1 to see if you can establish connection?

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?  If not, did you identify what was the cause?  Can you post it here as a self-answer to consider this question resolved if that's the case?

Answer (score 0):

Certain Google Cloud Platform products require SSL, you can simply enable SSL from your Cloud Console and it should work.

The documentation for [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl), for [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates), and for [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance).